# How long is the password for executing a command with sudo cached?

Tags: sudo, password, timestamps

If I run a command which requires root privileges with `sudo`, I will be asked to enter the current user's password. After that for a while, if I execute the same sort of commands with `sudo`, I won't be asked for the password again. So my guess is that the password is cached somewhere until it expires. How long is this expiration time? Is it possible to configure it?

Comment: Just fyi, you can prompt to extend the expiration using `sudo -v`. This is great for putting at the top of scripts that run sudo commands so that you're asked for the password at the beginning.

Comment: Note sudo does not actually cache the password.  Sudo does not actually need a password at all to do its job, it only askes so as to verify that the user allowed to run the given command.  Basically it caches the users credentials for a period (as a special "timestamp", see top answer), during which it does not require the user to re-verify themselves.  The password itself is not cached (stored), unlike a web browser or encryption keys.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`man 5 sudoers` informs us that there is an option `timestamp_timeout`:

> ```
> timestamp_timeout
> ```
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo
> will ask for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a fractional
> component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.  Set this to 0 to
> always
> prompt for a password.  If set to a value less than 0 the user’s time stamp will never expire.  This can be used
> to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via “sudo -v” and “sudo -k” respectively.

So yes, it can be configured via `/etc/sudoers`, and by default it expires after 5 minutes.

Also, please remember to use `visudo` to make any edits to `/etc/sudoers`. When saving your edits `visudo` will run validity checks before actually overwriting the sudoers file. This protects you from a painful recovery process if you lock yourself out of `sudo` access.

Comment: and you know, use `visudo` to edit `sudo` configuration, NEVER edit `/etc/sudoers` directly.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: True that. And (where possible) always keep another root shell open to be on the safe side. :)

Answer (score 10):

That depends on your configuration. The default on most distributions (and in the source) is 5 minutes, but you can change it with the `timestamp_timeout` option in `/etc/sudoers`. From `man sudoers`:

> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd again. The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5. The default is 5. Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password. If set to a value less than 0 the user’s time stamp will never expire. This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via "sudo -v" and "sudo -k" respectively.

For example, to set the timeout for user `chris` to 20 minutes, add the following to `/etc/sudoers`, or in a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` (note: both the order of rules in these files *and* the order of these files matters, make sure it is not unintentionally overridden by a rule which is executed later):

```
Defaults:chris timestamp_timeout=20
```