# Disable root password caching

Tags: sudo, password, root

How can I disable root password caching? I looked at [This Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77356/how-long-is-the-password-for-executing-a-command-with-sudo-cached), but I didn't really understand how to do it, is not the same as my question but it is indirectly related.

I tried adding this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
timestamp_timeout=0
```

But it gave me:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 46 <<<
```

So I just pressed `x`. 46 is the line where I added it, so there isn't a problem with anything else.

Comment: You need to enter `Defaults timestamp_timeout=0`. That is, you forgot the `Defaults`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=0
```

An example from [`man 5 sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers), where a value is appended to an option:

```
Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY HOME"
```

Comment: Mhm.. Thanks for that, I couldn't even find anything about searching on the internet.