# Why sudo permission does not expire when waiting long for input?

Tags: shell, sudo

For example, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Assume there are some updates to be installed. **Do not press anything**. Leave the terminal as it is. The shell will remain waiting for your input (y/n).

After a while (longer than the [default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77356/how-long-is-the-password-for-executing-a-command-with-sudo-cached) `timestamp_timeout`, e.g. one hour), go back to the terminal. **Press <kbd>Y</kbd>** (assuming you are fine with installing updates). The action will go through and the updates will be installed. This is, **the sudo permissions were still enabled, longer than the `timestamp_timeout`.**

Why is this behaviour possible? Is this a loophole in the shell/system security? Is this unsafe? Can this setting be modified?

Comment: Which of those two programs is issuing the prompt?

Comment: Because you are still running apt-get even when waiting for a response. The timeout will only apply when just sitting at the shell prompt.

Comment: The second one. In any case, that is just an example of a prompt (which is the one I used when I realised this).

Comment: The second one is already running as `root` so `sudo` is no longer involved and will not magically kill the already running command; the timeout is for future invocations of `sudo` not processes already running.

Comment: `timestamp_timeout` restricts how long `sudo` is willing to wait to let you run new commands without asking you for a password.  It doesn't limit the time said commands can run with increased privileges.  That was never the point of `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

sudo is used to run program as different user (f.e. root).

> Security policies may support credential caching to allow the user to
>   run sudo again for a period of time without requiring authentication.

If you already started program as different user and it's running, I think it's not desired to take away elevated privileges from running process, because it run from long time.

Caching is feature that allows you to run sudo multiple times within 5 minutes without prompting for password, not running command with elevated privileges for 5 minutes.

It's not even possible to change owner of process while it's running. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401774/change-owner-of-a-currently-running-process) for reference.